# Android sqlight with multiple where

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following table column

```
public static final String SHOWID = "show_id";
    public static final String SHOWNAME = "show_name";
    public static final String SHOWSEASON = "season_name";
    public static final String EPISODENAME = "episode_name";
    public static final String EPISODESTATUS = "episode_status";
```

I want to do the following query

```
SELECT episode_name , episode_status FROM tv_show WHERE show_name='aName' AND season_name='aSeason'";
```

How to do this??

I don't want to use db.rawQuery(...)

I want to use something like this

```
db.query(
                true,
                DBTABLE,
                new String[] {SHOWSEASON}, 
                SHOWNAME + " like ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(shName) },
                null, null, null, null
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic SQL, a quick search and you find the solution:

```
SELECT episode_name , episode_status FROM tv_show WHERE show_name='aName' AND season_name='aSeason'";
```

You have to use `AND`, not `&`

You can do something like that, and replace '=' with 'LIKE' if needed:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TVSHOW_TABLE, new String[] { EPOSIDENAME, EPISODESTATUS }, SHOWNAME + "='" + aName + "' AND " + SEASONNAME + "='" + aSeason + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Please see the edit i made in my question. and sorry for that silly mistake